# Calculating total cost of items entered by the user

Tags: python, input

> Trish at Bargain Used Books has hired you to write a Python program
> that will help her calculate what a customer should pay. She has a
> very simple price structure:
>
> - Workbooks are $8.50 each.
> - Textbooks are $24.00 each.
> - Magazines are $5.95 each.
>
> With every purchase, Trish also must charge 6% sales tax on the total.
>
> Create a file named Lab01P4.py. Write a program that calculates the
> cost for the total purchase:
>
> - Ask the user to enter the number of workbooks, textbooks, and magazines being purchased.
> - Calculate the total before tax.
> - Calculate the amount of sales tax on the total.
> - Calculate the total after tax.
> - Output the total before tax, the sales tax, and the total after tax.
>
> NOTE: Your program code should implement these steps IN THE SAME ORDER
> as listed above.
>
> All monetary values should be output with a precision of 2 digits
> after the decimal point. You should use what was presented in this
> lesson to achieve that result, that is, use f-strings. Points will be
> deducted otherwise.
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> Enter the number of workbooks: 7
> Enter the number of textbooks: 4
> Enter the number of magazines: 6
> Cost before tax: $191.20
> Sales tax: $11.47
> Cost after tax: $202.67
> ```

```
float(input('Enter number of workbooks: '))
float(input('Enter number of textbooks: '))
float(input('Enter number of magazines: '))
print(f'Cost before tax:{workbooks+textbooks+magazines})
```

I tried this, but I can't figure out how to get the number I input to add up the total. I just      started the class, but I need an example to understand, and I can't find one in my book or online.

Comment: `float(input('Enter number of workbooks: '))` This asks a question, but it doesn't save the answer to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn and not only searching for someone to solve your homework you should look into what variables are and how to use them.

Either way, here is a possible solution:

```
workbooks = int(input('Enter number of workbooks: ')) * 8.5 #number from input times price
textbooks = int(input('Enter number of textbooks: ')) * 24
magazines = int(input('Enter number of magazines: ')) * 5.95

cost = workbooks + textbooks + magazines #combined price of all three types
tax = cost * 0.06 # 6% of combined price -> tax
total = cost + tax # sum of combined price and tax

# combining all calculated values in an f-string using ':.2f' for 2 fixed digits after decimal 
print(f'Cost before tax: ${cost:.2f} Sales tax: ${tax:.2f} Cost after tax: ${total:.2f}')
```